# Logs Buffered calling Packer from Bamboo build task

Tags: logging, bamboo, packer

A Bamboo server build task is calling Packer to build a Windows VM. The packer build is 34 minutes, during which no log lines are emitted and displayed in the build logs. Once packer completes, all the log lines which were buffered are flushed and displayed in build logs but with identical time stamps, showing the time at the final second of the build.

I don't know if this is a Bamboo server (9.0) question or a Packer (1.4.2) question.

What can be done so packer log lines are emitted in real-time and displayed in Bamboo build logs in real time, with the actual time stamps of the events?

```bash
command_output=$(packer build -on-error=abort -var-file=variables/common.json -var-file=variables/api-base.json builders/vsphere_clone_base.json 2>&1) || {
  packer_build_error_code=$?
  error_message="Packer Build Command failed with exit code $packer_build_error_code and output: $command_output"
  printf "%s\n" "$error_message"
  if [[ $error_message == *"already exists"* ]]; then
    printf "VM already exists, exiting gracefully without error"
    packer_build_error_code=0
  fi
}
```

Comment: What's the command being used to kick off the packer build?

Comment: The root cause here would be Bamboo. Jenkins, Circle, Travis, GH Actions, GitlabCI, and Concourse all flush the Packer buffers if setup to do so in my experience.

Comment: @Paolo command added

Comment: Why are you executing packer in a subshell?

Comment: @Paolo If the VM already exists, packer will exit and I have to parse the command output to see "already exists", which is fine, no reason to fail the task. Without the subshell, packer will exit non-0 and the task will fail. Open to suggestions. I think the subshell might be at fault for the logging issue. Duplicated the behavior from bash script without involving Bamboo.

Comment: Why would you want your CI job to continue if the build fails?

Comment: It's not a failure when the image already exists, but packer returns non-zero, so consuming that and setting to 0.

So turns out the subprocess is indeed what is hiding the logs until that subprocess completes. I'll use pyvnomi to see if template exists in vsphere rather than letting packer detect it and abending due to it.